# Does it slow down to initializing an objects for all usres

Tags: php

I was wondering in php if i initialize a new object for each user that logs into my system and add all the users that are logged in a collection then access their methods and properties whenever needed will that slow down my system in the future if i start having more logins. i need to know what is the best method, is it to list all the users from the database using a static method or it is better off to initialize the object and assign their values to the right property then call those properties whenever i need them while using the system.

Comment: What is the purpose of saving all the logged in users in Single collection?

Comment: active users!! should i store them in a collection and then perform actions on them, or is it a waste of memory. users who are currently online. this is from the admin point of view. if i need to perform some action on those users from the admin panel.

Comment: It's good as long as you save minimum required details of user, may be userid of the users.